# Razor code EditorFor showing '�' as default?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

In my Form, there is a textbox, in razor code using EditorFor and the type given for this is **Char**.
But it always shows a '�' as default, what's that mean? is this because of **char** type?

please look at the picture[image]

Comment: its value is '�'

Comment: so where does that value come from? do you load it from a database? I'd suggest to watch it in the debugger. Include relevant parts of your source code so someone here might be able to figure it out. Does the problem disappear if you temporarily change the data type to `System.String`? related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15276191/1132334

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface If the field have value then it works fine, if it has no value ie the form open fresh, then it shows this symbol. Maybe it's because of the char type I don't know correctly.

Comment: the default value of the `char` data type is '\0' (U+0000) - looks like that's substituted by the invalid unicode code point glyph you see. Assign a space (' ') instead. Or question the design decision to represent quantity types by a char, make it a string. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43662939/1132334

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface Ok thank you, let me try with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This � is the invalid unicode code point glyph. It is what you will see in most browsers when they encounter the null character '\0' (U+0000).
This happens to be the default value of the .NET `char` data type.

Three workarounds:

1. substitute a valid char for the default, for example a space: `c == default(char) ? ' ' : c`
2. add logic to hide the `EditorFor` or `LabelFor` when the value is `default(char)`
3. change the data type to `System.String`, which leads to correct rendition in both cases `null` and `String.Empty`